# Network request failed occurred in expo project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, expo

During some days I faced Network request failed error in my expo project and my source code are given below: 
1.Home.js (in expo project)

```
export class Home extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Home',
        tabBarIcon: ({tintColor})=>{
            return <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" size={30} color={tintColor} />
        } 
    }
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = { posts: '' }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        try {
            fetch("http://127.0.0.1:3000/fetchTodo")
            .then(response=> this.setState({posts: response}))
            .catch((err)=>console.log(err));
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.response);
        }
        // console.log(posts);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>{this.state.posts}</Text>
                <Text>Home</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
export default Home;
```

2.api.js(inside node.js)

```
app.get('/fetchTodo',function(req,res){
        Todo.find({},function(err,data){
            if(err) throw err;
            // res.render('index',{data: data});
            // res.json(data);
            res.send('respond with a resource');
        })
    })
```

3.I found this type of error:

```
Network request failed

Stack trace:
  node_modules/whatwg-fetch/dist/fetch.umd.js:473:29 in xhr.onerror
  node_modules/event-target-shim/dist/event-target-shim.js:818:39 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:574:29 in setReadyState
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:388:25 in __didCompleteResponse
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/EventEmitter.js:190:12 in emit
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:436:47 in __callFunction
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:111:26 in __guard$argument_0
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:384:10 in __guard
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:110:17 in __guard$argument_0
  [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

**I have no idea how to resolve this error please any one help..**

Comment: It failed at the `app.get` part. Is your server running? Does the `/fetchTodo` endpoint exist?

Comment: Yup my server is running. I checked my route on postman,their I received suitable json data but it does not work for my expo project

Comment: Nothing is happened just error is display

Comment: Can you check if you're receiving anything in your `data` object? The issue could be with your `Todo.find`